# outputting proper complex json format from mysql

Tags: jquery, json

I have issues when I attempt to outputting record from mysql for complex json to send back to jquery...

my table

```
bil    iduser     name      experience
0       001       jacobs    bus driver 
1       002       max       painter
2       001       jacobs    racing driver
3       003       john      engineer
4       001       jacobs    retiree
5       002       max       designer
6       003       john      senior engineer
```

the desire json result is should be

```
[
    {
        "iduser":001,
        "name":"jacobs", 
        "exprience":[{"exp":"bus driver"},{"exp":"racing driver"},{"exp":"retiree"}]
    },
    {
        "iduser":002,
        "name":"max", 
        "exprience":[{"exp":"painter"},{"exp":"designer"}]
    }
]
```

and sort of....I'm okay with simple json format but this type of complex format I'm totally failed...stuck up here..

hope someone will shed me some light on how to format it by using php

Comment: Show your query and the array result.

Comment: #dqlopez here

$json = array();
$expArr = array();

$db = DataBase::getInstance();
if(is_object($db)){
 $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM sometable";
 
 $row = $db->executeGrab($sqlSelect);
 if(is_array($row)){
  $len = count($row);
   if($len>0){
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
     array_push($expArr, array('exp' => $row[$i]['experience']));
    }
    $dataArr = array('IDUSER' => $row[0]['iduser'],'NAME' => $row[0]['name'],'exprience' => $expArr);
    array_push($json, $dataArr);
   }else{
    //echo "NONE DATA";
   }
 }else if(is_bool($row)){
  //echo "BOOL";
 }

}

echo json_encode($json);

Answer (score 0):

First, get the output of the mysql result in an array using [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Then convert the array to JSON format using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: #vimalnath for single record and straightforward its ok with me ...but for repeated value kind of lost here...